# How to use universal image loader to download raw images WITHOUT DECODING

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, picasso, android-bitmap

I want to download images with `universal image loader` but **I do not want it to decode the images and create bitmap from it**. I just want to **save the original image** in a directory. how can I disabling it to decode?
Can I use other libraries? for example picasso but I think it can not do that, am I right?

Comment: What is 'decoding an image'?

Comment: And what is done with the bitmap?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean but I just want to download a raw image as it is on the server in to a directory.

Comment: That's what i thought already. Then why talk about decoding and bitmaps? Especiallt when you don't tell if the bitmap finally gets saved in that directory.

Comment: because universal image loader returns decoded image as a bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer would be:

```
    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.NONE)
    .build();
```

because of:

```
public enum ImageScaleType {
/** Image won't be scaled */
NONE,
```

from

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/blob/master/library/src/com/nostra13/universalimageloader/core/assist/ImageScaleType.java#L24